# Replacing multiple values in 1 column to a single value in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe called `data`. One of its columns is `data$activity`.

```
data$activity = c("eat", "sing", "dance", "sing", "eat and shop", "shop", "drinks",...)
```

I wish to replace specific values within the `data$activity` column to "Companionship" (string), and these specific values are stored in the following vector:

```
leisure = c("eat", "drinks", "shop", "eat and shop")
```

I tried the following,

```
data$activity[data$activity== leisure] <- "Companionship"

#to replace values in the 'leisure' vector that are found in data$activity, with the string, 'Companionship'
```

But error is: `Warning in data$activity == leisure : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R, we can create search terms that we want to replace (i.e., `"eat|drinks|shop|eat and shop"`). The `|` means "or", so we will look for eat or drinks or ... etc. If we find those terms, then we will replace them with `Companionship`.

```
data$activity <- gsub(paste(leisure, collapse = "|"), "Companionship", data$activity)

       activity
1 Companionship
2          sing
3         dance
4          sing
5 Companionship
6 Companionship
7 Companionship
```

Or with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(activity = str_replace_all(activity, paste(leisure, collapse = "|", "$", sep = ""), "Companionship"))
```

Or with your approach, you just need to use `%in%` rather than `==`, as you want to match to any value in `leisure`.

```
data$activity[data$activity %in% leisure] <- "Companionship"
```

Comment: Thank you! The last solution works for me. However, for the 2nd solution, "eat and shop" became "Companionship and shop"...

Comment: @Grace You're welcome! Oops didn't catch that. I've updated it, so should work properly now. I essentially just add in a`$` to specify the end of the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

This is working to me:

```
library(stringr)

data = data.frame(activity = c("eat", "sing", "dance", "sing", "eat and shop", "shop", "drinks"))

leisure = c("eat", "drinks", "shop", "eat and shop")

data[str_detect(data$activity, pattern = paste0(leisure,collapse = "|")) , "activity"] <- "Companionship"

data
#        activity
# 1 Companionship
# 2          sing
# 3         dance
# 4          sing
# 5 Companionship
# 6 Companionship
# 7 Companionship
```